# formData() not giving data after appending data

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, form-data

The 4th line gives form elements but 5th gives nothing here. what should i do?

```
$('#btnSave').click(function () {
                var form = $("#myForm");   
                var formData = new FormData($(form)[0]);
                console.log(form);//this gives form elements 
                console.log(formData);// but this gives nothing
                var url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>' + 'product/add';
                    $.ajax({
                        type                : 'post',
                        url                 :  url,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        data: formData,
                        success: function (response) {
                            if (response){
                                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                                $('#myForm')[0].reset();
                                $('.alert-success').html('Record Added').fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut('slow');

                            } else {
                                alert('Error');
                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert('could not add data');
                        }
                    });                       
                });
            });
```

//formData object append nothing with it. any solution please?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and make few changes in ajax code. Add below parameters in your code.

**processData: false,**
**contentType: false,**

And add `var formData = new FormData($("#formID")[0]);` line before ajax starts.

Or Check below code and make changes according to you code.

```
$('#btnSave').click(function (event) {
        var form = $("#myForm");   
        var formData = new FormData($(form)[0]);;         
        var url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>' + 'product/add';
         if($('#picture').val()==''){
             alert("please select the file");
         } else{
            $.ajax({
                type: 'ajax',
                data: formData,
                url: url,
                method: 'POST',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response) {
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                        $('#myForm')[0].reset();
                        $('.alert-success').html('Record Added').fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut('slow');
                        setTimeout(function () {// wait for 5 secs(2)
                            location.reload(); // then reload the page.(3)
                        }, 1);
                    } else {
                        alert('Error');
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('could not add data');
                }

            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks @pankaj but i have still that issue. review this again plz

Comment: just keep those things I've added in my code and add your code accordingly

Comment: remove lines from `var params = form.serializeArray();` to `console.log(formData);//not getting any data ` line from your code and add `data: formData,` below `type : 'ajax',` line

Comment: yes bro i have checked it but      var formData = new FormData($("#formID")[0]);     // i want to append input fields and a image file in formdata so i have to write some code after this line before $.ajax. like this                 var file = $("#picture").get(0).files[0];
                for (var i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
                formData.append(file);
                }
                
                $(params).each(function (index, element) {
                formData.append(element.name, element.value);
                });

Comment: May put quotes around `form` i.e. `new FormData($('form')[0]);`

Comment: check again brothers.

Comment: still not working bro :(. ive tried your edited changes .

Comment: Paste your code in pastebin.com and paste that link here

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is more than one mistakes, here i have code that i am using in ajax

```
          var form=document.getElementById('form_id');
          var fdata=new FormData(form);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'Your_url',
                dataType: 'json',
                data:fdata,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                beforeSend: function () {

                },
                success: function (data) {

                   //Do something on response
                },
                complete: function () {

                }
            });
```

Here your mistake is you are using `type: "ajax"`  that is not right way to write because you have to specify data passing method either POST or GET,

Second mistake in your code is, you have done two semicolon(;) on the 3rd line of your code, so that's reason javascript is not working.

I hope this will work for you.